# Error when running 'Make all' ERROR: The directory name is invalid make: Nothing to be done for `all'

Tags: c++, c, gnu-make

I am trying to set up a project from [this git repository](https://github.com/CominLab/MISSH/), but unfortunately, I have a problem compiling the program. Originally, when I ran `make all` command in my project's root, the error was this:

```
ERROR: The directory name is invalid.                                                                                   'Building target: build/ISSH'
'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
g++ -o "build/ISSH"    -fopenmp                                                                                         g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/ISSH] Error 1
```

I guessed that maybe the problem is that it cannot find the `build` folder, so I added the folder manually, and now, I have this error:

```
ERROR: The directory name is invalid.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

`makefile` commands:

```
USER_OBJS :=
LIBS :=

# define base directories and compiler
DEBUG_DIR := ./debug
BUILD_DIR := ./build
SOURCE_DIR := ./src
CC = g++


# if make debug was called, define directories accordingly and add -g flag
ifeq (debug,$(filter debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    OBJ_DIR := $(DEBUG_DIR)/obj
    DEPS_DIR := $(DEBUG_DIR)/deps

    CFLAGS = -g -std=c++0x -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -fopenmp

# if make clean all, define directories accordingly
else ifeq (all,$(filter all,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    OBJ_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/obj
    DEPS_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/deps

    CFLAGS = -std=c++0x -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -fopenmp
endif


ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    # if on windows, search for all .cpp files from sources directory
    CPP_SRCS := $(shell FORFILES /P $(SOURCE_DIR) /S /M *.cpp /C "CMD /C ECHO @relpath")

    # create objs and deps lists, and a list with all subdirectories to create inside OBJ_DIR
    OBJS := $(CPP_SRCS:$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
    CPP_DEPS := $(CPP_SRCS:$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d)
    TREE_WINDOWS := $(sort $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(OBJS))))
else
    # if on unix, search for all .cpp files from sources directory
    CPP_SRCS := $(shell find $(SOURCE_DIR) -name "*.cpp")

    # create objs and deps lists, and a list with all subdirectories to create inside OBJ_DIR
    OBJS := $(CPP_SRCS:$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
    CPP_DEPS := $(CPP_SRCS:$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d)
    TREE_UNIX := $(sort $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(OBJS))))
endif



# all target
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/ISSH

$(BUILD_DIR)/ISSH: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    $(CC) -o "$@" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS) -fopenmp
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '


# debug target
debug: $(DEBUG_DIR)/ISSH

$(DEBUG_DIR)/ISSH: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    $(CC) -o "$@" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS) -fopenmp
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '


# compile all dependencies for ISSH
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp | $$(@D)
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler'
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '


# create subdirectories tree, depending on which system we are

$(TREE_WINDOWS): %:
    MKDIR $@
    MKDIR $(@:$(OBJ_DIR)%=$(DEPS_DIR)%)

$(TREE_UNIX): %:
    mkdir -p $@
    mkdir -p $(@:$(OBJ_DIR)%=$(DEPS_DIR)%)


remake: clean-build all

remake-debug: clean-debug debug

clean: clean-build clean-debug

clean-build:
    $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)
    -@echo ' '

clean-debug:
    $(RM) -r $(DEBUG_DIR) 
    -@echo ' '
```

This is my current folder structure:

```
├───build
│   ├───deps
│   └───obj
├───Seeds
├───src
│   ├───Chrono
│   ├───Hash
│   ├───Input
│   ├───Parameter
│   ├───Spaced
│   ├───Test
│   └───Utilities
└───TestInputFile
```

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: `g++ -o "build/ISSH"    -fopenmp ` ? What  is `build/ISSH`  ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm not sure as I did not write the cmake file. But I guessed that it may be another folder whose existence is required for the `make all` to work but I added that as well and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: `g++ -o "build/ISSH"    -fopenmp`  There is not a single source file added in the command.

Comment: @ma_jafari `build/ISSH` is the output file for g++ command, not a folder. But strangley, the github page talks about `./MISSH` to run the resulting binary. That doesn't seem to match very well

Comment: It looks like `OBJS` is empty for some reason.

Comment: @Gerhardh Oh right. Thanks for the knowledge, I haven't worked with cmake before.

Comment: This isn't cmake, it's "regular" make.

Comment: Me neither, but `-o` specifies the output file name.

Comment: @molbdnilo I printed both `SOURCE_DIR` and `OBJ_DIR` and they were correct so I suppose that maybe `CPP_SRCS` is not being initialized correctly?